# Duplicate the music tracks of this player

Tags: jquery

I am new here and hope I'm not asking in the wrong area.
Well, I do not understand almost anything about JQuery but I've tried it a lot ... I'd like to duplicate the tracks on my player, with its control bar being just one. Explaining better; I wanted the tracks to appear in two places of the site and that by clicking one is like clicking the other as well. When using the controls (play, next etc) also work in both at the same time. In short, the **audio** tag will be one for both.
I organized the code to make it super simple and only the most essential:
in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1LkLdtxz/2/)

or right here:

CSS:

```
 body {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #212121;
  margin: 0;
  }
  .controls {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  }
  .seek-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  }
  .seek-bar .progress-bar {
  background-color: #1CE8B3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
  -o-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0;
  transform-origin: 0;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: transform 0.2s;
  -o-transition: transform 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  }
  .controls .buttons {
  width: 300px;height: 45px;
  left:0;right:0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  }
  .controls .play{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;height: 50px;
  left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
  margin: auto;
  }
  .prev {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;top:0;bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  width: 45px;height: 45px;
  }
  .next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto;
  width: 45px;height: 45px;
  }
  .tracks .track{padding: 10px;}
  .tracks .track .name{vertical-align: middle;}
  .track {background: #212121;}
  .track.active {background: #111111;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="controls">
    <div class="seek-bar"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
        <a class="prev">prev</a>
        <a class="play">play/pause</a>
        <a class="next">next</a>
</div>

<div class="tracks">        
    <div class="track active">
        <div class="name">música 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="track">
        <div class="name">música 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="track">
        <div class="name">música 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="track">
        <div class="name">música 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="track">
        <div class="name">música 5</div>
    </div>
    <audio class="music"><source src="http://audeficheux.com/projects/carousel/src/medias/0.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> Your browser doesn't support video API</audio>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
var Player = function ( $target )
{
    this.$ = {};
    this.$.body         = $target;
    this.$.prev             = this.$.body.find('.prev');
    this.$.next             = this.$.body.find('.next');
    this.$.play             = this.$.body.find('.play');
    this.$.seek_bar         = this.$.body.find('.seek-bar');
    this.$.progress_bar     = this.$.body.find('.progress-bar');
    this.$.tracks           = this.$.body.find('.tracks');
    this.$.music            = this.$.body.find('.music');
    this.$.track            = this.$.tracks.find('.track');

    this.count = this.$.track.length;
    this.init_events();
};

Player.prototype.index = 0;
Player.prototype.count = 0;
Player.prototype.progress_ratio = 0;

Player.prototype.init_events = function (){
    var that = this;

    this.$.next.on('click', function(){
        that.next();
        return false;
    });
    this.$.prev.on('click', function(){
        that.prev();
        return false;
    });

    this.changeMusic();

    this.$.play.on('click', function(){
        play = !play;
        that.changeMusic();
        return false;
    });

    /* when music ends */ 
    this.$.music.bind('ended', function(){
        that.next();
    });

    /**** seek-bar ****/
    window.setInterval(function () {
        this.progress_ratio = that.$.music[0].currentTime / that.$.music[0].duration;
        that.$.progress_bar.css({
          transform: "scaleX(" + progress_ratio + ")"
        });
    }, 50);
    /* change current music */ 
    this.$.seek_bar.on('click', function (e) {
            var x = e.clientX - that.$.seek_bar.offset().left,
            ratio = x / that.$.seek_bar.width(),
            time = ratio * that.$.music[0].duration;
        that.$.music[0].currentTime = time;
    });
};

Player.prototype.next = function()
{
    this.go_to( this.index + 1, this.index);
};
Player.prototype.prev = function()
{
    this.go_to( this.index - 1, this.index);
};

Player.prototype.go_to = function( index, currentIndex )
{   
    if (currentIndex != index) {

        index = index%this.count;
        if (index < 0)
            index = index + this.count;

        this.$.track[currentIndex].classList.remove('active');
        this.$.track[index].classList.add('active');
        /* change music source*/
        this.$.music[0].setAttribute('src', 'http://audeficheux.com/projects/carousel/src/medias/' + index + '.mp3');

        this.changeMusic();
        this.index = index;
    }
};

Player.prototype.changeMusic = function()
{   
    /* play/pause */    
    if (play == true) {
        this.$.play[0].classList.add('pausa');
        this.$.music[0].play();
    }
    else {
        this.$.play[0].classList.remove('pausa');
        this.$.music[0].pause();
    }
};

var $carousel = new Player( $('body') );
var play = false
```